# Why am I getting an error when using the requests module to return the server code?

Tags: python, module, python-requests, return, python-module

(I used a translator when writing this article. Please understand that some words may be incorrect.)
I tested it using the requests module. If the site cannot be found, a 404 code should be returned, but with an error. I don't know what the reason is. Any help would be appreciated. How to properly return a 404 code?

---Below is the code.

```
import requests as re
a = re.get(input())
print(a.status_code)
```

error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 515, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
p.prepare(
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 318, in prepare
self.prepare_url(url, params)
File "C:\Users\82104_dvfqr9f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 392, in prepare_url
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'eeee.com': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://eeee.com?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Oh I forgot the error. I don't know where the error is, so I put the full error.

Comment: The error tells you everything that you need to know. You inputed eee.com, this is not a valid scheme. Try http://eee.com

Comment: We want to return a 404 code, rather than not throwing an error.

Comment: Sorry. I just started coding, so there are a lot of things I don't know. I looked on the internet and saw that a 404 code was returned when an invalid url was entered.
I want to know how

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this link](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) for how to work with requests module.

```
import requests 
try:
   r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=ggg')
   print(r.status_code)
   if r.status_code==404:
      print("this url dosn't exist")
except Exception as error:
   print(error)
```